# Cannot send requests to my express API w/ redis after docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, redis

I've been working on a small project with Node.js/Express + redis, with basic frontend w/o any frameworks (full code can be seen [here](https://github.com/macc4/itrex-lab/tree/homework-6/project1)). I've been testing my API with Postman (because my frontend is currently not working), and it worked like a charm.

So, after implementing redis to the project, I've tried adding it to my docker-compose.yml file, here it is and some other files:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  redis:
    container_name: redis-db
    image: redis
    networks:
      - webnet

  backend:
    container_name: api
    build: ./backend
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    networks:
      - webnet
    depends_on:
      - redis

  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build: ./frontend
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    networks:
      - webnet
    depends_on:
      - backend
networks:
  webnet:
```

**config.yml**

```
server:
  host: localhost
  port: 8080
app:
  # '-1' for turning expiry off; otherwise, should be at least '1' (minute)
  timeToLive: -1
db:
  type: redis # ['in-memory', 'redis']
  redis:
    # select 'redis' if using docker-compose
    host: redis # ['localhost', 'redis']
    port: 6379
```

**redis.js**

```
import Redis from 'redis';
import config from 'config';
import AppError from '../utils/appError.js';
import { StatusCodes } from 'http-status-codes';
import { promisify } from 'util';

export const redisClient = Redis.createClient({
  host: config.get('db.redis.host'),
  port: config.get('db.redis.port'),
});

redisClient.on('error', function (err) {
  throw new AppError(err, StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
});

redisClient.on('connect', () => {
  console.log(' connected redis successfully ');
});
```

But, unfortunately, after docker-compose up I'm not able to make Postman requests anymore. Redis connected without any problems, in the console everything seems to be fine, and I even can access my frontend pages, but I cannot make requests to my backend anymore.

My frontend is running on localhost:5000, backend supposed to be running on localhost:8080, and redis seems to be running on redis:6379.

I've tried my best searching for the answer, but there are hundreds of questions on how to connect redis to your express project with docker-compose, but no questions about troubles accessing backend after connecting redis.

**EDIT_1**: here is what postman says:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/queue
Error: socket hang up
Request Headers
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.28.3
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: a61d8b9c-a2f5-4fe4-92e1-921a5680bb85
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
```

Here is docker ps output:

```
f7f6fbe12863   project1_frontend   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp, :::5000->5000/tcp   frontend
9802680a1a3d   project1_backend    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp   api     
66fde12be888   redis               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes   0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp, :::6379->6379/tcp   redis-db
```

And here are my console logs after docker-compose up:

```
api         |
api         | > queue-resolution-api@0.1.0 start /app
api         | > nodemon server.js
api         |
api         | [nodemon] 2.0.12
api         | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
api         | [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
api         | [nodemon] watching extensions: js
api         | [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
api         | NODE_ENV: development
api         | Listening on port 8080...
api         |  connected redis successfully 
redis-db    | 1:C 16 Aug 2021 14:35:18.728 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis-db    | 1:C 16 Aug 2021 14:35:18.728 # Redis version=6.2.5, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis-db    | 1:C 16 Aug 2021 14:35:18.728 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
redis-db    | 1:M 16 Aug 2021 14:35:18.728 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
redis-db    | 1:M 16 Aug 2021 14:35:18.729 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis-db    | 1:M 16 Aug 2021 14:35:18.729 # Server initialized
redis-db    | 1:M 16 Aug 2021 14:35:18.729 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
redis-db    | 1:M 16 Aug 2021 14:35:18.729 * Ready to accept connections
redis-db    | 1:M 16 Aug 2021 14:35:20.587 * DB saved on disk
frontend    | 
frontend    | > frontend@1.0.0 start /app
frontend    | > nodemon server.js
frontend    |
frontend    | [nodemon] 2.0.12
frontend    | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
frontend    | [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
frontend    | [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
frontend    | [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
frontend    | Listening on port 5000...
```

Comment: Do you have any logs?

Comment: Not sure how you were running your app in docker and connecting it to a local redis before given the backend would be connecting to "localhost", unless you were using a host network. As Sergio said, you need to add in Postman / CURL logs

Comment: I've added Postman log and some console logs to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the answer. In my server.js file I've been forcing the app to listen on **host** = localhost, and after deleting the host part everything started working.

```
app.listen(port, host, () => {
  console.log('NODE_ENV: ' + config.util.getEnv('NODE_ENV'));
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`);
});
```

Comment: Just so others know, you might need to run `minikube ip` to get the container IP that you can use to access your web app.